# Facebook Android Application - Login Issues - "An Error Occured"

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I have had the Facebook SDK running on my android application for a while now.  I have mostly been testing it with the Facebook Application installed.  But today, I was testing it on a Kindle Fire.

My Repro Steps are as follows....

1)  Login to Facebook through the Browser Application. (No FB Application installed)
2)  Login to my Android Application using the Facebook SDK
3)  Go back to the browser and log out of Facebook.
4)  Return back to my application....When I refresh my UIWebView, you are no longer authorized for the FB Application...thus now we are back to the 'login' screen
5)  Try to Login to Facebook again...

You received a blank FB Login Page with "An Error Occured".

Note:  The Url it is trying to use for the login page, (1) has my correct applicationId, and it also contains an auth_token.

You can not log into the application until you goto the Application settings and "Clear Data."  Once you do that, you can then log in again.

Has anyone else seen this problem?   When I first implemented the FB SDK, I pretty much copied the sample application.

Thanks,
stringa

Comment: you can clear application data in your mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried something like this and it worked.

```
Utility.mFacebook.authorize(this, permissions, -1,
                                      new LoginDialogListener());
```

When you set the activitycode to -1 , you will be prompted with Login for sure. It means you are forcing it to open the login dialog.

Comment: The above didn't work for me.  I am noticing this problem when having the auth_token in the LoginDialog URL.  If you remove the auth_token parameter from the url, it works great!  You don't wanna remove the auth_token for anything else though....just the login dialog.